# OPENCV: Why the result of cv::affine3d(4x4) times cv::vec3d(3 dimensions vector) is still CV::Vec3d?

Tags: c++, opencv

```
void function( ..... cv::Affine3d pose,....)
{
  cv::Vec3d z_axis(0.0, 0.0, dev->len);
  cv::Vec3d plane_vec = pose * z_axis;// the result of plane_vec is [-60.5844, 48.1445, -17.4011]
}
```

In my opinion, pose is a 4x4 matrix which contains a 3x3 rotation matrix, a 3x1 translation matrix and a row containing 0001, and z_axis is an array containing 3 numbers.
why does this happen? it seems not obey the rule of matrix multiplication.

Comment: It's not matrix multiplication between 4x4 matrix and 3x1 vector, see [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/76350cd30f6c4697b5be7968ba0b8ab9cc28b64c/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/affine.hpp#L630)

Comment: If you think it should be a 4x1 vector, have a look at homogenous coordinates. Probably just 1 ist added as 4th element and later removed again.